# creating animation using pictures of something

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation

i am currently trying to create a fish pond with fishes in it, i have parts of these fishes which i hope i can join them together to create a animation of a fish and be able to control it easily, as i will have to implement some AI on the fish, such as moving to eat a food etc. i am very new to flash and have no idea how can i go about doing this, how can i combine the images to form a fish and then be able to control the whole fish and have it move naturally like a fish without much knowledge of AS3?
[image: the fishes part]

Answer (score 0):

Place each piece of the fish onto a new layer within a MovieClip. From here make sure each part of the fish is also a MovieClip or a Graphic. Now you can animate each piece easily using the timeline; creating tweens or frame by frame animations. Having a fish have multiple types of movement can be achieved either all on the one timeline using some ActionScript, or you could segment each animation into its own MovieClip which will be placed onto its own frame in the main fish MovieClip.

Hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: whether if the fish piece is a movieclip or graphic symbol is there any difference?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you create a Movieclip, lets call it Fish_MC, and connect that movieclip to a class, lets call it Fish.

Inside of the Fish_MC, you can dedicate each frame to a "state" that the fish will be in. For example, have one frame for swimming slow, one frame for swimming fast and one frame for biting. On each of those frames, create a new movieclip that will contain the animation for the coressponding state that the fish is supposed to be in.

The Fish class can contain all of the AI for the fish and have a "setState" method that changes which frame (ie state) the Fish_MC is on using a call to gotoAndStop.